# What is the minimum and maximum cutoff frequencies for the antialiasing filter for this ADC?

Tags: filters, analog-to-digital, hardware, anti-aliasing-filter

https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad9675.html

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9675.pdf

It says in the data sheet that the Anti-Aliasing Filter has :
"Programmable second-order low-pass filter (LPF) from
8 MHz to 18 MHz or 13.5 MHz to 30 MHz and high-pass
filter (HPF) "

So does that mean the minimum cutoff frequency is 8MHz and the maximum is 30MHz?

And also making sure but the min sampling frequency is 20.5 MHz, max sampling frequency is 125 MHz, and the dynamic range is 75 dB, right?